# Trying to use auto for that, but the compiler gives error "element doesn't name a type"

Tags: c++

My program provides a class `Student` that takes 3 scores, and takes average of two best.  It needs to print best and worst averages.

I tried using minimax, but compiler doesn't like `auto` type, and gives error        *"element doesn't name type"*.  Not sure if this is correct approach.  Someone else in my class has done this by creating an array for min and max    separately.

Here is the code:

```
int main ()
{
 vector <Student> myClass; // vector of my class Student
 fillvector (myClass);    //asks user input to fill scores of students
 printVector (myClass);  // prints the data
 auto element = std::max_element(myClass.begin(), 
                                myClass.end(), comparator);
                     // not working
}
```

Comment: Is that the first error?  Perhaps you forgot to include `<algorithm>`

Comment: That error sounds like you don't have C++11 enabled.

Comment: If you need both the min and max, it's worth pointing out that there's a `std::minmax_element` algorithm.

Comment: If your class implements `operator <` or `operator >`, you don't need to pass a comparator predicate.

Comment: Thanks for the help..! Appreciate it.!